# Finish Build trigger does not fire for feature branch

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have a TeamCity project configured with 2 build configurations 'A' and 'B'.  The 'A' configuration is meant to run against a feature branch and build the solution.  It also publishes packages to the team city nuget feed.

I am also using the Octopus Deploy teamcity plugin to automate the creation of releases and deployments in our Octo server.  Any packages published by a build configuration to the TeamCity nuget feed are not available to any build steps within the same build configuration so a second build configuration must be created to consume the packages.

As a result the 'B' build configuration is the Octo deployment step and it has a snapshot dependency to build A and an artifact dependency to build A.  The artifact dependency has 'Get artifacts from' set to 'Build from the same chain'.

The build chain runs without issues when run with the teamcity vcs default branch.  However the 'B' build config does not trigger when the 'A' build config runs against a feature branch.  When looking at the build chain in teamcity when a build occurs on a feature branch the 'B' build config says 'Not Triggered'.

I can't find any clear solution to this problem and whether or not this is actually supported by TeamCity.  It sounds like in earlier versions of TeamCity (~v7) this was not supported but that the introduction of snapshot/artifact dependencies solved the issue.

Comment: There's a different way to configure this and it can be done in one build configuration, but it depends on a few things. Are you pushing the package to OD's internal library too, or pulling it from the TC nuget feed in OD?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd I am aware that using a nuget feed other than the built in TC feed will allow me to use 1 build configuration which will remove the need for a deployment specific build config and the reliance on the currently non-firing Finish Build Trigger.  At this point I would really like to know if anyone has successfully fired Finish Build Triggers when using feature branches in TC.  Documentation and third party blogs seem to indicate it works I would really like to set the record straight :)

Comment: Yes, they do work provided your second configuration can build off of the same branch specifications - thus it probably needs the same VCS settings to understand the branches

Comment: Hrm that could be the issue because as of now I have no VCS settings configured for the 2nd build config as it did not need to interact with source control (my thinking was that it was just using artifacts from Build 'A').